# Rails 4 - Nested Object Won't Save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

Note: I've read a couple posts similar to this. But non of the solutions answer my question

I have two objects, Bid and Moz. When I build my Bid object, everything seems to save okay, except for the Moz objects.

**Model**

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :mozs, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :mozs, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Moz < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bid
end
```

**Bids::Build Controllers**

```
class Bids::BuildController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

  steps :intro, :problems, :solutions, :pricing

  def show
    @bid = Bid.find(params[:bid_id])
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @bid = Bid.find(params[:bid_id])
    @bid.attributes = build_params
    4.times { @bid.mozs.build } if step == steps.second
    render_wizard @bid
  end

  def new
    @bid = Bid.new
    redirect_to wizard_path(steps.first, :bid_id => @bid.id)
  end

  def build_params
    params.require(:bid).permit(:client_name, :intro, :prob1, :prob2, :prob3, :site_feel, :search_phrase, :page_score, :total_links,
                                :internal_links, :external_links, :competition, :complete, :user_id, :us_company, :philosophy_1,
                                :philosophy_2, :website_conclusions, :is_onsite_seo, :onsite_seo, :is_ongoing_seo, :ongoing_seo,
                                :is_ppc, :ppc, :is_social_media, :social_media, :is_google_places, :google_places, :is_adwords_express,
                                :adwords_express, moz_attributes: [:url, :id, :_destroy]
                                )
  end

  private

  def finish_wizard_path
    root_url
  end
end
```

**solutions.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for (@bid), url: wizard_path do |f| %>
  <% if @bid.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@bid.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this bid from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @bid.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if @bid.is_onsite_seo? %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :onsite_seo %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :onsite_seo %>
  </div>

  <% end %>
  <% if @bid.is_ongoing_seo? %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ongoing_seo %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :onsite_seo %>
  </div>

  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ppc %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :ppc %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :social_media %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :social_media %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :google_places %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :google_places %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :adwords_express %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :adwords_express %>
  </div>


  <%= f.fields_for :mozs do |builder| %>
    <%= render partial: "moz_fields", locals: {f: builder} %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association "Add URL", f, :mozs %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
    or <%= link_to "skip this step", next_wizard_path %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**_moz_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="field fields">
<%= f.label :url, "Comparative URL" %><br>
<%= f.text_field :url %>
<%= f.hidden_field :destroy %>
<%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)"%>
</div>
```

I don't understand why they won't save. In addition, I noticed something odd -- when I don't use a partial for the nested object and use the `f` form builder for the @bid object (as opposed to 'builder'), I get an error `no method or variable :url`, but a Moz object is saved (although, not with any of the desired attributes).

Comment: Don't you need to `@bid.save` in `create`?

Comment: @UriAgassi create is actually being used in the bids_controller.rb. What I'm doing is creating the bid and updating the attributes in steps using the Wicked gem. I'll get rid of that create so it's less confusing.

Comment: So where _do_ you `save` the bid?

Comment: @UriAgassi I save the bid in the create action in the bids_controller

Comment: Have you looked at the actual request using something like better errors?  If i have something like this i use better errors and just put in some jibberish in the controller so that I can see what the value of the variables are.  Also, does it create everything as expected using the rails console?

Comment: @Austio I haven't used better errors. I'll look into that. In the rails console, the records are created just fine.

Comment: If it works in the console, but not through a controller action, more often than not it's strong_parameters that is biting me. Check your log for `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for…`.

Comment: I agree with @janfoeh this is most likely related to strong parameters and wicked not playing well with your nested attributes

Comment: @janfoeh I don't have any reference to mass-assignment in my logs. In fact, I only have one warning in the log referencing `link_to_function` deprecation. Would there always be that error if it's an issue with strong params?

Comment: Yes, if strong_parameters isn't complaining about dropping values, we'll have to look elsewhere.

Comment: It's been a very long day and I shouldn't be on SO anymore, so forgive me if this is a stupid question, but: why the `f.hidden_field :destroy`?

Comment: @janfoeh Thanks for spending so much time on this. I'm using the hidden field to help dynamically create and destroy a field for the child record. It's from a solution I found at railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Sure, what I meant was: won't a hidden destroy field always destroy the child record, or rather, prevent it from being created? Also, try replacing you `@bid.create` call with `@bid.create!`. Exceptions on save might make debugging a bit easier.

Comment: Also, could you show us the params hash as received by the controller from your logs?

Comment: @janfoeh Yeah, removing that did the trick. Maybe I didn't understand the use of that field correctly, but shouldn't it just prevent blank entries from being created? Either way, that was the answer. I'll mark yours as the right answer if you add it. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, although on second glance I am not really certain why. Is it really `f.hidden_field :destroy`, or is it `f.hidden_field :_destroy`? The latter should have the effect you're seeing, provided its value is "1", the former should just be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send the parameter `_destroy: 1` through your hidden field

```
<%= f.hidden_field :destroy %>
```

you instruct Rails to destroy the child `moz` object, or in your case, prevent it from being created.

As for the second part of your question, if you inline the partial from this

```
<%= f.fields_for :mozs do |builder| %>
  <%= render partial: "moz_fields", locals: {f: builder} %>
<% end %>
```

to this

```
<%= f.fields_for :mozs do |builder| %>
  <div class="field fields">
    <%= f.label :url, "Comparative URL" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
    <%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

it won't work, because the model object for the scope `f` is your `@bid`, not `moz`. Bids have no url attribute, hence the error.

With the input fields being created in the wrong form builder scope, you did not actually transmit any attributes for your `moz` object, and so it was created blank. As a side effect, this also meant not sending the `_destroy` parameter, so the object was saved.

Instead, inline the partial like this (I renamed `builder` to `moz` for clarity):

```
<%= f.fields_for :mozs do |moz| %>
  <div class="field fields">
    <%= moz.label :url, "Comparative URL" %><br>
    <%= moz.text_field :url %>
    <%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

My opinion that you misspelled with permit attrbibutes hash, try to change `moz_attributes` to `mozs_attributes`.

```
params.require(:bid).permit(..., :mozs_attributes: [:url, :id, :_destroy])
```